# Serial Port Data Issue

Tags: java, arduino, microcontroller

I have a network configuration as:

Arduino--Xbee-->  <--Xbee-Arduino--> Java App on PC

I had burnt a code into the Sender node to send 1s continuously to the Receiver. But what i see is that even after burning a new code into the Sender to send different values, i keep getting the 1s in the receiver end and not the latest values. How do i get over this problem? Is there a way to flush the previous unwanted data?

The code that i use is from a tutorial that i found in the arduino website. Copy pasting the same below:

```
Receiver Code: Java

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier; 
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent; 
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener; 
import java.util.Enumeration;


public class SerialTest implements SerialPortEventListener {
    SerialPort serialPort;
        /** The port we're normally going to use. */
    private static final String PORT_NAMES[] = { 
            "/dev/tty.usbserial-A9007UX1", // Mac OS X
            "/dev/ttyUSB0", // Linux
            "COM3", // Windows
    };
    /**
    * A BufferedReader which will be fed by a InputStreamReader 
    * converting the bytes into characters 
    * making the displayed results codepage independent
    */
    private BufferedReader input;
    /** The output stream to the port */
    private OutputStream output;
    /** Milliseconds to block while waiting for port open */
    private static final int TIME_OUT = 2000;
    /** Default bits per second for COM port. */
    private static final int DATA_RATE = 9600;

    public void initialize() {
        CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
        Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

        //First, Find an instance of serial port as set in PORT_NAMES.
        while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
            CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
            for (String portName : PORT_NAMES) {
                if (currPortId.getName().equals(portName)) {
                    portId = currPortId;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (portId == null) {
            System.out.println("Could not find COM port.");
            return;
        }

        try {
            // open serial port, and use class name for the appName.
            serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(this.getClass().getName(),
                    TIME_OUT);

            // set port parameters
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE,
                    SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                    SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

            // open the streams
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));
            output = serialPort.getOutputStream();

            // add event listeners
            serialPort.addEventListener(this);
            serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

    /**
     * This should be called when you stop using the port.
     * This will prevent port locking on platforms like Linux.
     */
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (serialPort != null) {
            serialPort.removeEventListener();
            serialPort.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handle an event on the serial port. Read the data and print it.
     */
    public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
        if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
            try {
                String inputLine=input.readLine();
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
        // Ignore all the other eventTypes, but you should consider the other ones.
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SerialTest main = new SerialTest();
        main.initialize();
        Thread t=new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                //the following line will keep this app alive for 1000 seconds,
                //waiting for events to occur and responding to them (printing incoming messages to console).
                try {Thread.sleep(1000000);} catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
            }
        };
        t.start();
        System.out.println("Started");
    }
}
```

Comment: your question is not clear, does not provide a code example of what you've attempted so far, what gets wrong (is it the arduino that is sending 1s continuously, or the xbee module), you use terms that are not defined (what do you call "mote", the arduino or the "xbee" device?) and you don't tell what kind of xbee dongle you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I had burnt a code into the Sender node to send `1`s continuously to the Receiver. But what i see is that even after burning a new code into the Sender to send different values, i keep getting the 1s in the receiver end and not the latest values. 
>   How do i get over this problem?

You shall reflash your Arduino. Try reflashing with `2`s instead of `1`s, and back, you'll see it'll stop sending `1`s.

> Is there a way to flush the previous unwanted data?

The data itself is gone away on every unplugging of your Arduino.

It looks like your Arduino code did not get uploaded to the board, either you had a connection problem, or your new arduino code is not compiling. Have a good look at the error message the IDE compiler should be returning.